# How do i avoid blocking an express rest service?

Tags: node.js, express, event-loop

When making a REST service using express in node, how do i prevent a blocking task from blocking the entire rest service? Take as example the following express rest service:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello, World'));

const blockService = async function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const end = Date.now() + 20000;
        while (Date.now() < end) {
            const doSomethingHeavyInJavaScript = 1 + 2 + 3;
        }
        resolve('I am done');
    });
}

const blockController = function (req, res) {
    blockService().then((val) => {
        res.send(val);
    });
};

app.get('/block', blockController);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('app listening on port 3000'));
```

In this case, a call to /block will render the entire service unreachable for 20 seconds. This is a big problem if there are many clients using the service, since no other client will be able to access the service for that time. This is obviously a problem of the while loop being blocking code, and thus hanging the main thread. This code might be confusing, since, despite using a promise in blockService, the main thread still hangs.  How do i ensure that blockService will run a worker-thread and not the event-loop?

Answer (score 1):

By default node.js runs your Javascript code in a single thread.  So, if you really have CPU intensive code in a request handler (like you show above), then that is indeed a problem.  Your options are as follows:

1. Start up a Worker Thread and run the CPU-intensive code in a worker thread.  Since version 10, node.js has had worker threads for this purpose.  You then communicate back the result to the main thread with messaging.
2. Start up any other process that runs node.js code or any type of code and compute the result in that other process.  You then communicate back the result to the main thread with messaging.
3. Use node clustering to start N processes so that if once process is stuck with a CPU intensive operation, at least one of the others is hopefully free to run other requests.

Please note that a lot of things that servers do like read files, do networking, make requests to databases are all asynchronous and non-blocking so it's not incredibly common to actually have lots of CPU intensive code.  So, if this is just a made up example for your own curiosity, you should make sure you actually have a CPU-intensive problem in your server before you go designing threads or clusters.

Comment: Do i understand correctly that long-running tasks such as a network request (ex via fecth) that could take any arbitrary amount of time relies on the underlying library to spawn the new threads for it's async nature then? I assumed that a big point of the worker thread-pool is so that long-running async tasks will run on a different thread, and avoid blocking the main thread. But is there then no easy way to push the task onto the worker-thread pool?

Comment: @DanielValland -  All networking in node.js is completely non-blocking.  It doesn't even use threads.  It uses OS-level asynchronous I/O.  You do NOT have to worry about networking blocking the event loop.  It doesn't.  node.js is one of the more efficient development tools for doing lots and lots and lots of networking because of its asynchronous design whereas a threaded environment could use up a lot of system threads (which consume significant resources) for a lot of networking calls in progress.  The asynchronous I/O design of node.js is very efficient for lots of I/O.

Comment: @DanielValland - FYI, file I/O does use a thread pool inside of libuv in its implementation.  But, that's entirely transparent to you.  It's still completely non-blocking to your Javascript.  The thread pool just means there's an absolute limit to the number of file operations that are actually running in parallel, but that's not necessarily a bad thing since a disk can only do so many things at once anyway since the read head can only be in one place at a time. Once you have more file I/O requests than the size of the thread pool, additional requests go in a queue until a prior once finishes.

Comment: @DanielValland - The disk I/O thread pool is again transparent to you and so is the number of threads in it.  Queuing is automatic if you exceed the size of the thread pool so it's really just an internal implementation detail that does not affect your programming in any meaningful way.  But, if you opened 100 file operations at once, you'd only be making parallel progress on a few of them at once.  When one finishes, the next one in the internal queue would start.  This is actually more efficient than trying to time slice 100 actual disk operations.

Comment: Thanks. I know networking is plain sailing in node. What i am more worried about is that i occasionally have to do some iteration (or filter, map and forEach etc...)  or other things that are blocking, and i am worried that some blocking code initiated by a client (in the case of an express app) will disproportionately affect the rest of the clients. In that case i would like to ensure that blocking code will run on a worker thread, so that blocking can be distributed among many threads, and hanging will not affect the rest of the application as much.

Comment: @DanielValland - Just know that solutions to that exist if there is an actual problem in real world code.  But, don't try to optimize something and add worker complication before you've measured and proven there's an actual problem.  `.filter()`, `.map()` and `.forEach()` are wicked fast, even for thousands of items.  Modern CPUs are really fast.  If you want to show some actual code for us to look at, we can offer you some thoughts, but even then, you will still have to measure to see if a worker thread is called for or even worth it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I sure will. I have a fairly large project. Will look trough it. I just don't like the thought of a lot of concurrent requests doing iteration of potentially large arrays that could have been done in async on multiple threads, but that end up being sequentially done on the same thread. I had imagined there would be something akin to syntactic sugar to allow for explicit non-blocking execution.

Comment: @DanielValland - There is no syntactic sugar for automatic threading in node.js (as of 2020).  There is a cost to involving a thread so it's not considered a lightweight thing that you just do all the time for a particular loop of code.  In fact, the lack of using a separate thread for each incoming request (like some platforms/frameworks) is one of the things that makes nodejs particularly efficient and trouble free at some types of code.  Bu, if you want to or need to push some execution off to a thread, you can write some code that will do that using Worker Threads.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is an event-based model that uses a single runtime thread.  For the reasons you've discovered, Node.js is not a good choice for CPU bound tasks (or synchronously blocking tasks).  Node.js works best for coordinating I/O asynchronously.

[worker-threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) were released in Node.js v12.  This allows you to use another thread for blocking tasks.  They are relatively simple to use and could work if you absolutely need the offload blocking tasks.